# Looping through ASP.NET GridView with Jquery to get ID's of Checked Rows

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am having an issue with this.

I have a gridview with checkboxes in the first column and then the row id in the next column. I need to loop through the grid and if the row is checked I need to append the id to a string.

My issue is that the ids variable is bringing back a comma separate string of "undefined"s. Basically I need the correct way to get the ids from the gridview.

```
   $("#test").click(function ()
        {
            if (Validation() === true)
            {
                var q = 0;

                var obj = {};
                obj.status = $("#dlStatus").val();
                obj.type = $("#dlType").val();
                obj.title = $("#tbTitle").val();
                obj.description = $("#tbDescription").val();

                var selectedItems = "";
                $("[id*=cbList] input:checked").each(function ()
                {
                    selectedItems += $(this).val() + ",";
                });

                obj.selectedjobs = selectedItems;

                var selectedGroups = "";
                $("[id*=cbGroups] input:checked").each(function ()
                {
                    selectedGroups += $(this).val() + ",";
                });

                obj.selectedgroups = selectedGroups;
                if ($("#FileUpload1").val())
                {
                    obj.materialurl = $("#FileUpload1").val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '')
                }
                else
                {
                    obj.materialurl = "null";
                }
                var id = getQueryVariable("ID");
                if (id != false)
                {
                    obj.id = id;
                }
                else if (id === false)
                {
                    obj.id = "0";
                }
                var ids;


---------------------ISSUE CODE BELOW-------------------------------------------
                var selids;
                var gvDrv = document.getElementById("<%= GridView2.ClientID %>").getElementsByTagName("tr");
                for (i = 1; i < gvDrv.length; i++)
                {
                    var checkbox = gvDrv[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
                    if (checkbox.checked)
                    {
                        selid = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').val();
                        }
                        ids += selid + ",";
                }

-----------------------ISSUE CODE ABOVE----------------------------------------
                obj.selectedassoc = ids;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/InsertData",
                    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (r)
                    {
                        var s = r.d;
                        $("#lblResult").css("color", "green");
                        $("#lblResult").css("font-size", "13");
                        $("#lblResult").html(s);
                        if ($("#FileUpload1") != null)
                        {
                            $("#test2").click();
                        }
                    },`enter code here`
                    error: function ()
                    {
                        $("#lblResult").html("There was an error sending the information.");
                    }
                    });
                 }
                 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
var checkbox = gvDrv[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
if (checkbox.checked)
```

You could try:

```
checkbox = gvDrv[i].find('input[type=checkbox]')
if (checkbox).prop('checked')==true)
```

Hard to tell from the question where the actual issue is though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help Stack Overflow. ha jk

Figured it out.

corrected code.

```
 $("#test").click(function ()
    {
        if (Validation() === true)
        {
            var q = 0;

            var obj = {};
            obj.status = $("#dlStatus").val();
            obj.type = $("#dlType").val();
            obj.title = $("#tbTitle").val();
            obj.description = $("#tbDescription").val();

            var selectedItems = "";
            $("[id*=cbList] input:checked").each(function ()
            {
                selectedItems += $(this).val() + ",";
            });

            obj.selectedjobs = selectedItems;

            var selectedGroups = "";
            $("[id*=cbGroups] input:checked").each(function ()
            {
                selectedGroups += $(this).val() + ",";
            });

            obj.selectedgroups = selectedGroups;
            if ($("#FileUpload1").val())
            {
                obj.materialurl = $("#FileUpload1").val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '')
            }
            else
            {
                obj.materialurl = "null";
            }
            var id = getQueryVariable("ID");
            if (id != false)
            {
                obj.id = id;
            }
            else if (id === false)
            {
                obj.id = "0";
            }
            var ids = "";

            var CustomerIDs = "";
            var grid = document.getElementById('<%=GridView2.ClientID %>');
            var selid = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < grid.rows.length; i++)
            {
                var Row = grid.rows[i];
                var ctrl = Row.cells[0].childNodes[1];

                if (ctrl.type == "checkbox")
                {
                    if (ctrl.checked)
                    {
                        selid += Row.cells[1].innerHTML + ",";
                    }
                }
            }
            obj.selectedassoc = selid;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/InsertData",
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r)
                {
                    var s = r.d;
                    $("#lblResult").css("color", "green");
                    $("#lblResult").css("font-size", "13");
                    $("#lblResult").html(s);
                    if ($("#FileUpload1") != null)
                    {
                        $("#test2").click();
                    }
                },
                error: function ()
                {
                    $("#lblResult").html("There was an error sending the information.");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```